# Include external setup files in setup.txt TYPO3

Tags: typo3, typoscript

is it possible to outsource some setups into different setup files, e.g. like menus or language setups? I want my setup.txt to stay clean.

Thanks for your replies :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For including additional setup files you can use the INCLUDE_TYPOSCRIPT - Tag. Here is an example:

```
<INCLUDE_TYPOSCRIPT: source="FILE:fileadmin/TypoScript/menu.txt">
```

For the people who keep their setup file in an extension.

```
<INCLUDE_TYPOSCRIPT: source="FILE:EXT:ext_name/Configuration/TypoScript/Setup/setup.txt">
```

Be sure, that you place the include-tag at the right position in your setup.txt

Hope that helps

Comment: Please don't  advice people to put their TypoScript files under fileadmin. This is considered a bad practise.

Comment: True that. But the question is not specific enough. Should have covered both opportunities

Comment: Thanks, the INCLUDE-Tag is exactly what i've been searching for :)

Answer (score 3):

This is possible, you can include single files with

```
<INCLUDE_TYPOSCRIPT: source="FILE:EXT:my_ext/Configuration/TypoScript/Setup/Config.txt">
```

It is also possible to include directories recursively:

```
<INCLUDE_TYPOSCRIPT: source="DIR:EXT:my_ext/Configuration/TypoScript/Setup/" extensions="txt">
```

Comment: Not all Typo users are using setup files from extentions^^

Comment: Well, they should... :) Puting configuration files into fileadmin is not a good practise.

Comment: Agreed as mentioned i should've covered both opportunities

Comment: Thanks for your answer :)